# How would I display this Json data in PHP

Tags: php, json

```
$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create($charge);
Stripe\Charge Object
(
    [id] => ch_1Bt8DmKeJztnq1RQBMCphYpl

    [source] => Stripe\Card Object
    (
        [card_id] => card_34dfshghoyui856
        [object] => card
    )
)

$ID = $charge[id];
$object = $charge[source]->object;
```

I'm trying to get the data for object. ID works, but the object doesn't.

Comment: print `$charge` array and show us..

Answer (score 0):

Php 7.1 or 7.2 (to be checked) has now a reserved keyword `object`. You shouldn't use a property with such a name.

Or use special syntaxes $charge->source->{'object'}